# Find out if a certain application / command is available on Linux?

Tags: c, linux

I need to know if xclip (the command is installed) because if it is available I want to send a command to it via the system() function, otherwise I want to display a message. Is there a way to know if the command exists?

Thanks

I mean programably

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For something like xclip, you can just do:

```
if (system("xclip")==-1) // Check for command execution failed
  ...
```

and check the return value. A -1 indicates that xclip was not found. Or, you can execute something like:

```
if (system("which xclip")==0) // Check if command can be found
  ...
```

and check for a 0 return, indicating no failed arguments.

Comment: If the program could not be run, 127 is returned. But I don't find the specification of that return code.

Comment: From the system(3) man page: In case /bin/sh could not be executed, the exit status will be that of a command that does exit(127).

Comment: Thanks. I used: if (system("which xclip", ignore.stdout = TRUE) == 0)

Answer (score 0):

The `which -s` command can take in the name of a command and set `$?` to 0 if it could find it, 1 otherwise